SFML executable throws errors and doesn't open
I have a game in SFML and built it using cmake. Now I would like to create an executable for the game. To achieve it I have built it in release mode and got the cmake-build-release directory, where I found the executable.
But when I run the executable file in cmake-build-release\bin it throws 2 sequential "Entry Point Not Found" popup windows which says:

"Couldn't locate an entry point for procedure _ZNSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11 char_traitslcESalcEE15_M_replace_c oldEPcуPKcуy not found in library .../cmake-build-release/bin/sfml-graphics-2.dll".
"Couldn't locate an entry point for procedure ... not found in library .../cmake-build-release/bin/sfml-window-2.dll"

I have all of my dll files in the directory with the executable.
When I build and run the program through CLion it runs without any issues.
I am using CLion with the bundled MinGW toolset, gcc/g++ compiler.
This is how my CMakeLists.txt looks like:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(MagicianFest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)


include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        SFML
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/SFML/SFML
        GIT_TAG         2.6.1
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

add_executable(...)

target_link_libraries(MagicianFest sfml-graphics sfml-system sfml-window sfml-network sfml-audio)

My goal is to create an executable file, so maybe there is a different approach to achieve this. I am open to all kind of suggestions.

...(long string of characters) The errors must be complete and verbatim embedded in another code block.

Does this answer your question? How to debug DLL issues in MinGW?

"I have a game in SFML and built it using cmake. Now I would like to create an executable for the game." -- We have different concepts of building a game. I would not consider the game "built" unless an executable was created. What exactly was built?

"(long string of characters)" -- I'm guessing that you mean a long string of characters that you find meaningless. That does not mean others will find it meaningless. In fact, maybe the reason you don't know the answer to your question is because you don't know the meaning of these characters. In which case, including these characters in your question would be critical for getting an answer.

What we concluded in the staging ground is either, 1. The mingw compiler dlls are not on your PATH or 2. You have a different compiler installed on your system that is picked up by CMake when outside of Clion, you want to use https://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find out the problem

Try the debugging steps from the suggested duplicate. Do you have the same issue with simple "hello world", or it only happens with SFML? Compare the environment (e.g. PATH variable) in your CLion and in the console outside CLion. Also some build output and EXACT execution output would be useful.

@JaMiT, 3CxEZiVlQ, edited out and included the whole procedure’s name

@AhmedAEK, I guess you were right, but I decided to go a way around and to not use the mingw in the end, but the visual studio toolset. Thank you for the help, dependency walker turned out to be useful.

@pptaszni, after building the simple programs, the executable worked. So I suppose it is only the problem with SFML

In the end it turned out to be the problem with the mixed compilers. I found out through using dependency walker on the executable that there was a MSVCRT.dll, which, I guess, meant that program was using msvc compiler, which lead me to not using the default MinGW toolset with its g++ compiler, but the Visual Studio Toolset (with cl.exe) which I had already downloaded before.
Solution: I just change the default MinGW toolset to Visual Studio Toolset int the CLion settings and built this way.
Now the executable file which is located in the cmake-build-debug-visual-studio folder works without flaws.
